# Biblatex reference error

Tags: biblatex

I have found an annoying error as mentioned in the graph below (the error is marked "x" in line 90). The error says: --syntax error: found "IS", expected ","--

[image]

And here is the lines above it:

[image]

I don't know what's the error here, seems like I have implemented the correct syntax. For the record, line 104 - 115 is the example or template for the Biblatex usage, I've tried to follow it and implement it to line 90-100. Does someone know what mistake that i did there?

Thank you and kind regards.

Comment: don't use spaces in key names.  Also please show code in a text block not as an image, which is much harder to debug

Comment: ah you're right, it works now. Got it, will do next time. Thank you very much for the help! @DavidCarlisle

Comment: Regardless of the expected output, multiple names in the `author` field (and similar fields) must be separated with `and`. So `S. K. Au, J.L. Beck` is wrong and should be `S. K. Au and J. L. Beck`. Likewise a literal `et al.` is not correct either. It is usual to include all authors in the `.bib` file and let the style decide whether or not to "et al." some authors. If you insist on only giving a subset of authors, use `and others` instead of `et al.`. `and others` is a special keyword that is recognised automatically as "et al.".

Comment: @moewe Ah I see, indeed I've been trying to overcome that problem. Thank you so much! I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use spaces in key names The error is telling you it wants a comma after the key `adaptive` but it found `IS` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, really appreciate it.